robots.txt working in local but not uat server
I am trying to the robots.txt on my UAT server. I am able to access the robots.txt locally with localhost:9001/food/robots.txt.
However, I am not able to access it when it is on my UAT server with example-uat.com/food/robots.txt. It shows
'This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 401'

when I try to access it in the UAT server. HTTP error 401 shows authentication error. MY UAT server is hosted on AWS with elastic container service.
What is the cause of this?

401 indicates a permission issue.

Can you access other URLs on the webserver aside from /food/robots.txt?
What webserver software are you using?
What user account does the webserver run under?
Provide a directory listing of the directory/folder that contains the robots.txt file, in a way to show the file permissions.  In Unix use ls -l


I have found out the issue for this as it seems that i have blocked them through my backend. However on my lighthouse it still shows that robots.txt is invalid and it shows html for that
